# Need to find a design plan to this problem related to a real time scenarios. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Tags: database-design, bigdata, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

A fleet of 1000 cabs in the warehouse are tracked by multiple fleet managers. Sensors from each cab generates Telematics data & location information. All the telematics data can be captured in to an Azure data lake in two ways.

1. Data can be streamed using live connection.
2. Data can be downloaded manually to a local storage when cab comes to garage and then push it to data lake.

The telematics data in Azure data lake is used to create various reports on the cab performance and build analytical models like Proactive Maintenance. The data is huge (~ 600GB/Day) and should managed in data lake such a way that some of the technical users can do self servicing/querying on this data.

Fleet managers should be able to track the cab's live location on the map. Personal/Sensitive data should be hashed and Data should be managed within the region. That is data generated from APAC region should stay within the same region and should not be accessed outside the region. Historical data up to 10 year to be available for data scientists to build analytical models.

Need to come up with a Design / Architecture with appropriate  Toolset in Azure with your assumptions while proposing the solution to address the above said problem statement.

i tried using Azure Event hub and went for synapse to track the live mode. It seems its not a proper solution for the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, following are the use cases and the corresponding Azure services to be used:

- Send async messages or support event driven services - Azure Event Grid or Azure Service Bus
- Add firewall, intelligent routing, end to end SSL, scaling - Azure Application Gateway and Azure Load Balancer
- Host DNS domain - Azure DNS
- Observability into the services, infrastructure and network - Azure Monitor
- Setup and host containers - AKS
- Customer Identity and Access Management - Azure Active Directory External Identities
- Monitor cloud spending - Microsoft Cost Management
- Track Live Location - Azure Maps API or Google's Geolocation API
- Data Analytics - Azure Data Lake Storage
- Store Historical and Telematics Data - Azure Managed Instance for Apache Cassandra
- Mask personal data - Azure Functions (customized code based on the use cases) to scrub the personal data before storing it to DB
- Notify the fleet manager that the cab is due for service or any relevant action to be taken - Azure Batch and Azure Service Bus

All of these are set up in the same Azure Region but across different Availability Zones.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to point out any miscellaneous microservices that you may require, but from what I see, you dont need to do real-time analytics with tools like spark streaming or ASA (Azure streaming analytics). Instead you want to create reports from the data hosted in your ADLS as your end goal.

You can still use ASA in combination with event/IoT hub as in this example from the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-solution-patterns#archiving-real-time-data-for-analytics

This would be useful even if you dont need to do real-time analytics and it will give you a chance to do some changes to data when its required. This is how the "Core" of your infra would look like

Then you can use something like spark notebook in databricks or spark pools in synapse to create dashboards (or any other external tool) from your big data stored in ADLS. Likely spark or parallel processing is your only solution as the data you say has quite high volume and velocity.

To further enhance your architecture, you can employ anomaly detection in ASA and detect anomalies real-time before the fleet managers see it in their dashboards

Comment: Thanks , I guess the documentation will help :)